# How do I globally redirect an ip address in Pyramid?

Tags: python, pyramid, pylons

Is there a global way to redirect users w/ certain ip's in pyramid? Right now, we have to redirect on a view by view basis.

For instance, each view will return 'my custom message' for every page someone w/ ip address of 'xyx.xxx.xx' visits. If you don't have that ip address, then the page will load as normal.

```
@view_config(renderer="json", route_name="myview")
def myview(request):
    redirector(request)
    ......
def redirector(request):
    if request.remote_addr.startswith('66.'): return viewA(request)
    else: return 'my custom message'
```

Is there a way we could redirect globally in pyramid (other than through .htaccess)?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use  [`Pyramid`'s `events` system](http://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid/en/latest/narr/events.html) :

```
@subscriber('pyramid.events.NewRequest')
def newrequest(event):
    request = event.request
    if request.remote_addr.startswith('66.'):
        raise SomeException('my custom message')

@view_config(context=SomeException, renderer='string')
def exc_view(exc, request):
    return exc.message
```

Comment: pyramid gets more and more awesome the more I learn about and use it. It's a very well thought out framework. Thx for your help on my question as well as your contributions to the framework. Big fan here!